# derivation of the electic displacement D

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, maxwell-equations

I've been revising Maxwell equations recently and tried to prove that the electric displacement $ \mathrm{\nabla \cdot D = 0}$ in the electrostatic approximation ($\mathrm{E = - \nabla} f$). My steps are as follows:

Starting off with the definition:

$ \mathrm{c\nabla \times B = 4\pi j + \frac{\partial E}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial D}{\partial t}} $

Then taking divergence of the both sides:

$\mathrm{ 0 = 4\pi\nabla \cdot j + \frac{\partial \nabla \cdot E}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial \nabla \cdot D}{\partial t} }$

Thus,  I conclude that $\nabla \cdot \mathrm{D} = \mathrm{const}$

**Q**: How do I apply the electrostatic approximation to prove that the $\mathrm{const}=0$?

Comment: It doesn't. It equals a constant.

Comment: I've seen $\nabla \cdot \mathrm{D} = 0$ was used to derive the wave equation in the electrostatic approximation.

Comment: That would simply be a medium with no free charge. What is a wave equation in electro*statics*??

Comment: I also don't understand where you get your expression for the time derivative of D being c curl B. I thought it was just CGS, which I am not used to, but now I don't think so. Maybe you should define all your symbols.

Comment: The wave equation in the _electrostatic approximation_ means that there is no magnetic field and we can replace the electric field **E** by $\nabla \phi$ where $\phi$ is the potential. Concerning to your question about curl B equals the time derivative of D. If I understand correctly it is the definition of D.

Comment: I've never said that $E = -\nabla \phi$ is the wave equation. What I mean is that $E = \nabla \phi$ is the _electrostatic approximation_. In general, $E$ is not potential. Also, I am almost sure that the electric displacement $D$ and $E$ both have the same units.

Comment: OK, maybe we're getting sonewhere. I guess I just don't follow CGS. Isn't $c\nabla \times B = 4\pi j + \partial E/\partial t$. So why do you say the RHS is $\partial D/\partial t$?  Either way, there is no need for the divergence of D to be zero except where there is no free charge density.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31715/discussion-between-kirill-and-rob-jeffries).